# Kubernetes V1.6.2 unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d

Tags: kubernetes

Based on this (https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/) step I have installed Kubernetes in Centos 7 box and ram the kubeadm init command.

But node is not in ready status. When I looked the /var/log/messages. getting below message.

```
Apr 30 22:19:38 master kubelet: W0430 22:19:38.226441    2372 cni.go:157] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Apr 30 22:19:38 master kubelet: E0430 22:19:38.226587    2372 kubelet.go:2067] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
```

My kubelet running with these arguments.

```
 /usr/bin/kubelet --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --require-kubeconfig=true --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --allow-privileged=true --network-plugin=cni --cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.d --cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin --cluster-dns=10.96.0.10 --cluster-domain=cluster.local --authorization-mode=Webhook --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --cgroup-driver=systemd
```

in my server I didn't see /etc/cni/net.d directory. in /opt/cin/bin directory I see these files.

```
# ls  /opt/cni/bin
bridge  cnitool  dhcp  flannel  host-local  ipvlan  loopback  macvlan  noop  ptp  tuning
```

How can I clear this error message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you've chosen flannel as CNI-networking.
Pls check if you've specified --pod-network-cidr 10.244.0.0/16 while kubeadm init.

Also check if you've ConfigMaps created for flannel as in here @ https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml

Comment: thanks, I have to create the two deployments. kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel-rbac.yml
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem cause by kuberadm first init coredns but not init flannel,so it throw "network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized".
Solution:
1. Install flannel by `kubectl -n kube-system apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/bc79dd1505b0c8681ece4de4c0d86c5cd2643275/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml`
2. Reset the coredns pod
`kubectl delete coredns-xx-xx`
3. Then run `kubectl get pods` to see if it works.

if you see this error "cni0" already has an IP address different from 10.244.1.1/24".
follow this:

```
ifconfig  cni0 down
brctl delbr cni0
ip link delete flannel.1
```

if you see this error "Back-off restarting failed container", and you can get the log by

```
root@master:/home/moonx/yaml# kubectl logs coredns-86c58d9df4-x6m9w -n=kube-system
.:53
2019-01-22T08:19:38.255Z [INFO] CoreDNS-1.2.6
2019-01-22T08:19:38.255Z [INFO] linux/amd64, go1.11.2, 756749c
CoreDNS-1.2.6
linux/amd64, go1.11.2, 756749c
 [INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = f65c4821c8a9b7b5eb30fa4fbc167769
 [FATAL] plugin/loop: Forwarding loop detected in "." zone. Exiting. See https://coredns.io/plugins/loop#troubleshooting. Probe query: "HINFO 1599094102175870692.6819166615156126341.".
```

Then you can see the file "/etc/resolv.conf" on the failed node, if the nameserver is localhost there will be a loopback.Change to:

```
#nameserver 127.0.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

[github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/48798)

Comment: I was getting error. I have installed coredns and restart `systemctl restart kube-proxy.service kubelet.service`. working file for me

Answer (score 1):

if you are in AWS ... I'm using cloud formation yaml's, I suggest that you match your Kubernetes version AMI with the Region+ID:

Kubernetes Version 1.13.8
Region:                   US East (N. Virginia) (us-east-1) 
Amazon EKS-optimized AMI: ami-0d3998d69ebe9b214

then apply your mapping:

```
kubectl apply -f aws-auth-cm.yaml
```

Then watch the magic:

```
kubectl get nodes --watch
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-workers.html

Answer (score 0):

none of the above solutions didn't worked for me.
I found out that my server does not have default route!

```
# route -n
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp9s0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

so I added the default gateway by the following command:

```
# route add default gw 19.168.1.1
# route -n 
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp9s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp9s0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

right now the `iptables` works fine